# Incomplete DateTime In C#

Tags: c#

In C# if I want to parse a datetime, but some times I just have either a date and not a time component or no date but a time component, how would I do this? Usually when you leave out the time component, it automatically assumes that the time is 12:00AM. But I don't want this. If the time component is missing then I just want the `DateTime` to store a date only and the leave the time component off.

Answer (score 17):

The value of a DateTime internally is just an `UInt64` (`ulong` in C#) that stores the number of ticks since some date in the past, so whether you like it or not, the time component will always be there.

Comment: +1, DateTime is really a bunch of utility methods wrapped around an integral value.

Comment: The internal value is actually unsigned, though it makes little difference as far as usage.

Answer (score 9):

If you only need to *display* certain parts, just use any of the format strings (examples are for "en-us" culture):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d"); // 5/26/2009
DateTime.Now.ToString("t"); // 4:56 PM
```

The complete reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to have a `DateTime` without a time component. You could store a boolean flag along with it in a `struct` to store data about existence of that component. However, there's no way to use the automatic parsing routine to distinguish between a `DateTime` string with a time specified as `12:00 PM` and a nonexistent one.

Answer (score 5):

If it really bugs you you can always create a wrapper class that can hide the time portions of the datetime class.

Answer (score 4):

No you will have the time component no matter what.  The best you can do is access the Date property on your DateTime object if you really have to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: The Date property is still just a DateTime with the time component set to midnight.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime by definition stores a date and a time such that it cannot just represent one of them without representing the other.  If you only want the date (or only the time), parse out the information you need and discard the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before DateTime will always have a Date and a Time part of it if you only want a single part use the way described by the others

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2009-11-30);
date.Year; = 2009
date.Month; = 11
date.Day; = 30
date.Hour; = 0
and so on
```

The thing you must be aware is that all of these methods will only return an integer.

If you want to know all the possible ways to parse a string John Sheehan has put together a great [Cheat Sheet wit all possible ways to parse and manipulate dates](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf), and other strings for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class that stores a DateTime and determines if the time was ever set or if just the date was set and return values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime object is always stores a date + a time, not just one. You can always choose to work only with the date part, i.e. only use properties like Year, Month, DayOfWeek. But underneath there will aways be some stored time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2001");
```

to set the date, then use

```
date.ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
date.Year;
date.Month;
date.Day;
```

to get what you need.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is very dangerous to assume that the date portion of a `DateTime` is necessarily the date you are expecting.  As pointed-out, `DateTime` always includes and considers the time aspect, even when you don't see it.

This is a big problem when you have data stored in different time-zones (and particularly if knowledge of that offset is not also kept, because it is assumed that what is being stored is a Date, not a date-with-time).

You may store a birthdate as '01/01/2000 00:00:00' during Summer-Time, which then is stored in UCT as '31/12/1999 23:00:00'.  When you then read that birth-date later, the date portion is now a day early.

Best to create your own type.  Strange that Microsoft didn't think it worth having a `Date` type.